# Loop through array in JS and generate posts for HTML feed in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, feed

So I have a basic Bootstrap website in HTML set up like a news feed and I'm trying to fill it with different posts. In Javascript, I have arrays containing different images, headlines, and captions that I want to use to generate the posts in the news feed. My first thought is to just loop through the arrays and generate the HTML code for each post, and then insert that code into the feed `<div>` using Javascript.

However, I have been using string variables in Javascript for storing the generic HTML code for each post and concatenating them with the image url, headline text, etc to create the code block for each post. This has been really awkward going, making me think there has to be a more efficient way of going about generating code for content posts in a feed.

Anyone know of a more efficient method for programatically creating the posts to fill this feed?  Ideally, I would be able to avoid just writing the HTML for each post by hand (there are >50 posts that I'm trying to create) and I would have some control over the order of the posts, etc.

Here is an example of the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <title>NewsMe Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NewsMe</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <br></br>
            <h2>News Feed</h2>
<!--             <p>Find all the </p> -->
        </div>
  <a href="https://ibb.co/YjH9b25"></a>
    </div> 
    <div class="row" id="feed">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <img src="http://eskimo.egemenerd.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/product14-600x600.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="news-content">
                                            <a href="#"><h2>Headline 1</h2></a>
                                            <p>Caption 1 </p>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="news-footer">
                                        <div class="news-author">
                                            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                                                <li class="list-inline-item text-secondary">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                                    Author
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="list-inline-item text-secondary">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                                    News
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="list-inline-item text-secondary">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                                                    110 Views
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="list-inline-item text-secondary">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                                    26 June 2018
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>   
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <img src="http://eskimo.egemenerd.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/product14-600x600.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="news-content">
                                            <a href="#"><h2>Headline 2  </h2></a>
                                            <p>Caption 2</p>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="news-footer">
                                        <div class="news-author">
                                            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                                                <li class="list-inline-item text-secondary">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                                    Author
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="list-inline-item text-secondary">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                                                    110 Views
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="list-inline-item text-secondary">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                                    26 June 2018
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>   
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
                      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                      <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
<!--        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img src="http://eskimo.egemenerd.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/blog17.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #e2e5ee;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

/*--- navigation bar ---*/

.navbar {
  background:#4e4764;
}

.nav-link,
.navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-link {
  margin-right: 1em !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

img {width:100%;}
```

The Javascript:

```
var img_arr = ['image_1.png','image_2.png'];

var headline_arr = ['Headline 1', 'Headline 2'];

var caption_arr = ['Caption 1', 'Caption 2'];
```

Comment: Please just add the relevant portion of the code. All the boilerplate bootstrap code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jQuery and it can be easy

Make a space for the posts to be rendered

```
<div id="posts">
</div>
```

Make a template for a single post and hide it by default

```
<div style="display: none;" id="templates">
    <div id='post-template'>
        <span id='post-caption'></span>
        <span id='post-headline'></span>
        <img id='post-image' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Loop over your objects in JavaScript to **clone** the templates and append them in the posts div

```
let posts = $("#posts");
for (let i = 0; i < caption_arr.length; i++) {
    let caption = caption_arr[i];
    let headline = headline_arr[i];
    let image = img_arr[i];

    let postClone = $("#templates #post-template").clone();

    postClone.find("#post-caption").text(caption);
    postClone.find("#post-headline").text(headline);
    postClone.find("#post-image").attr('src', image);

    posts.append(postClone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [placeholder API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) to fetch fake posts and more.

A working example using your code structure:

```
let img_arr = []
let headline_arr = []
let caption_arr = []

fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      headline_arr = data.map(p => p.title)
      caption_arr = data.map(p => p.body)
  })


fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      caption_arr = data.map(p => p.thumbnailUrl)
  })
```